# List value assignment within for loop

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

What can I do when I get the following error in this code?

```
def reverse_word(word):
    index = len(word)
    new_word = []
    for i in range(index - 1, -1, -1):
        new_word.append(word[i])
    return ''.join(new_word)
def reverse_sentence(sentence):
    l = sentence.split()
    for i in l:
        l[i] = reverse_word(i)  
        l = ' '.join(l) 
    print(l)    
a = "Hello !Nhoj Want to have lunch?"   
reverse_sentence(a)
```

> `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.`

What can I write instead of this line:

```
l[i] = reverse_word(i)
```

Comment: I think you want to do something like `for i, w in enumerate(l):` and `l[i] = reverse_word(w)` and move from the loop your list build. I'm not sure you algorithm is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... this line: `l[i] = reverse_word(i)` throws an error because `i` is a string (`word`), but in `l[i]`, `i` **must be an index**.

You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
words = sentence.plit()
new_sentence = []
for i,word in enumerate(words): #or just for word in words, you don't need the index
    new_sentence.append(reverse_word(word))
```

and then join at return time `return ' '.join(new_sentence)`

This implementation follows your logic but uses strings instead of lists.

```
def reverse_word(word): 
    new_word = ''
    for i in range(len(word) - 1, -1, -1):
        new_word += word[i]
    return new_word

def reverse_sentence(sentence):
    r = ''
    for word in sentence.split():
        r += reverse_word(word) + ' ' 
    return r[:-1]

>>> a = "Hello !Nhoj Want to have lunch?"   
>>> reverse_sentence(a)
>>> 'olleH johN! tnaW ot evah ?hcnul'
```

Comment: This answer is ok,but possible to do something?